# D3 pie chart disapears from map

Tags: javascript, d3.js, topojson

I started from a sample Map app at: http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/raw/5193723/

I want to place a custom pie chart, as shown in the fig below. I created one by adding the code snippet just after the creation of circles is done.

**Pie-chart Snippet**:

```
        var r=10;
        var p = Math.PI*2;

        var arc = d3.svg.arc()
                .innerRadius(r-3)
                .outerRadius(r)
                .startAngle(0)
                .endAngle(p* d.value1);
        var arc2 = d3.svg.arc()
                .innerRadius(r-7)
                .outerRadius(r-4)
                .startAngle(0)
                .endAngle(p* d.value2);

        g.append("path")
                .attr("d", arc)
                .attr("fill", "red")
                .attr("transform", "translate(400,500)");
        g.append("path")
                .attr("d", arc2)
                .attr("fill", "orange")
                .attr("transform", "translate(400,500)");
```

It comes out nicely as shown in the pic below near Thailand:[image]

**Problem**

1. When I zoom or move the map, the pie-chart disappears but the circles remain intact. Can someone help me understand it?
2. One can notice a very crude way the arcs are plotted. The pie-chart is expected to be plotted for each of the city. I am looking for a cleaner way just like the way circles are drawn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code that runs when zoom takes place

```
    g.selectAll("path")  
        .attr("d", path.projection(projection));
```

is selecting all paths and modifying their `"d"` attribute. Since it's "generically" just looking for `paths`s, then it's also grabbing the donut paths you created and modifying them (probably setting them to empty strings or `NaN`s).

You can fix this either by taking the donuts out of the same `g` of the geo paths, so that they don't get selected. **OR**, you can make your `"path"` selector more specific, by adding some class (e.g. `"geo"`) to all the geo paths and using that class whenever you select them (e.g. `g.selectAll("path.geo")`).

Comment: Here's an [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/RdFtHkLnMrbxoAo0xn7H?p=preview) implementing @meetamit's second idea.

Comment: Thanks @Mark for putting that together!